# How to know if there is an index on a list and access the value of that index in python

Tags: python

I want to know if an index exists in the list, and access its value, but I don't know how to do it. What I need is something like this:

```
my_list = ["a", "b", "c"]
if(my_list[3] == "d"):
 print("Something")
elif(my_list[3] != "d"): 
 print("Something again")
```

I want to do something if there is a third index, if not, do nothing.

**Note** that what I need is to check if "d" is in index 3, if instead of having a "d" in index 3 there is something else it falls into the elif block, however, if there is no index 3, do nothing

Comment: `if len(my_list) > 3:  ...`  - then you have the indexes 0,1,2,3 ( or more) ... ? Or the other way round: `highest_index = len(my_list)-1` ...

Comment: @Patrick Artner  It turns out that I can only have a maximum of 3 indexes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to know whether third index exist or not:

```
my_list = ["a", "b", "c"]
if(3 in range(0,len(my_list))):
  if my_list[3] == 'd':
    print("Something")
  elif(my_list[3] != "d"): 
    print("Something again")
```

Answer (score 0):

You will get 'IndexError: list index out of range' if you run the code.
If you mean the third elements in the list, it's my_list[2]
This can be written backwards using 'in' or 'not in' .

```
my_list = ["a", "b", "c"]

if "d" in my_list[2]:
    print("Something")
else:
    pass
```

Comment: It turns out that "d" is for is always in index 3, in your list there are only 2, so I need to check if there is an index 3, and if there is, check if the content is "d" or not

Comment: if you don't know know the actual length of the list, use try-catch to write the code.

Comment: I don't think he accidentally wrote `my_list[3]` instead of `my_list[2]`, he actually meant `my_list[3]` - but he wants to check if it's there AND if it contains the right element

Answer (score 0):

you can just use **try - except** block

The try block lets you test a block of code for errors.

The except block lets you handle the error.

```
my_list = ["a", "b", "c"]
try:
    # if index exist it will execute this part of code
    if(my_list[3] == "d"):
        print("Something")
    elif(my_list[3] != "d"): 
        print("Something again")
except IndexError:
    print ("index doesnt exist")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this snippet code which returns `True` or `False`:

```
def index_in_list(a_list, index):
    print(index < len(a_list))


a_list = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
if len(a_list) == 4:
    index_in_list(a_list, "d") # output: True
```